# cd.. and cd- commands not found - how do I use the cd command?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I am using Precise pangolin. As far as I know, commands like

```
cd..
```

or

```
cd-
```

are used to browse through folders in the terminal.

But whenever I enter one of this commands, it gives an error saying `no such command or filename found`. Do I have to perform any additional task before I use commands involving `cd`?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you typing `cd..` or `cd ..` Note there is a space.

Comment: Why are the downvotes? Looks like a good question for me

Comment: Can you edit your question to show actual text from the terminal that you're using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Common Commands

View Directories:  `ls`

The `ls` (LiSt) lists files in different colors with full formatted text

Create Directories:  `mkdir` (directory name)

The `mkdir` (MaKeDIRectory) command will create a directory.

Change Directories:  `cd` (`/directory/location`)

The `cd` (ChangeDirectory) command will change from your current directory to any directory you specify.

Copy Files/Directories: `cp` (file or directory name) (to directory or filename)

The `cp` (CoPy) command will copy any files you specify. The `cp -r` command will copy any directories you specify.

Remove Files/Directories: `rm` (file or directory name)

The `rm` (ReMove) command will delete any filename you specify. The `rm -r` command will remove any directory you specify.

Rename Files/Directories: `mv` (file or directory name)

The `mv` (MoVe) command will rename/move any file or directory you specify.

Find Files/Directories: `locate` (file or directory name)

to go back to previous directory: `cd ..`(cd [space] ..)

just for extra information

source from http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg24t7.htm

Answer (score 7):

To browse directories you use `cd dirname`. So if you're in your Home and you want to go to Downloads you type `cd Downloads` ,if you want to go to a folder inside it you do the same again `cd subFolder`. If you want to go to a specific folder you type `cd Downloads/subfolder/folder2/`.

If you're in another folder that isn't inside your Home folder structure but want to go to a folder inside of it (Home) you add this character `~` so it's something like this:

`user@user-desktop:etc/$ cd ~/Downloads/subFolder/folder2/`

`user@user-desktop:~/Downloads/subFolder/folder2/$`

That will take you directly to a folder inside your Home structure because of the `~`.

To return to your Home you just type `cd`.  To go up 1 directory you type `cd ..`

Comment: Thanks Uri for the elaborate reply. The problem is I know most of the commands for browsing, but whenever I am entering them in my terminal (of Precise Pangolin) it just says "cd..:command not found" as if such command(s) do(es) not exist. Is that a problem with my ubuntu installation or my terminal or do I need to install some app or do something else before I use those commands or they have changed the commands in Ubuntu 12.04 in some significant way?

Comment: You're typing `cd...` it *doesn't* exist it's `cd -space- ..`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do put space between cd and .. like this `cd ..`

`cd` represents change directory.

`cd ..` is used to go back from child directory to parent directory.

You can check your current directory using `pwd` (present working directory).

Type `ls -l` it will list all the files and directory. Use cd 
and you will be directed in specified directory.

for more help type `man cd`