# chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory

Tags: directory

I'm using ubuntu `14.04 LTS`, I want to install xampp but encountering

```
chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What command did you enter? Perhaps the file you are trying to use is not available in that directory.

Comment: sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to run your `chmod` in the wrong directory (a directory where your `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run` file is not available).

Navigate to the correct folder using `cd` (refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179681/how-do-i-use-the-cd-command) for more information on the `cd` command):

```
cd /<folder-where-the-file-is/
```

Then run your command again.

---

I assume you are trying to XAMPP, so here is the full installation procedure if you still can't run your command :

```
wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.5.28/xampp-linux-x64-5.5.28-0-installer.run
chmod +x xampp-linux-*-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```